# Quelle est l'origine du mot « ultra(-)droite » et comparaison avec la locution « extrême droite » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, origine-ou-raison, préfixes, politique

Je lis un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/201903/18/01-5218678-lultra-droite-menace-croissante-et-bien-identifiee-en-europe.php) qui réfère au nom [*ultra(-)droite*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ultradroite#fr) et à la locution nominale [*extrême droite*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/extr%C3%AAme_droite) selon les intervenants ([source](http://www.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1903/16/cnr.22.html) de la traduction d'un intervenant anglophone : [*far-right*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/far_right)). Wiktionnaire indique qu'*extrême droite* est un quasi-synonyme d'*ultra(-)droite* et qu'*ultra(-)droite* est apparenté à *extrême-droite*. Je ne connais pas le terme [*ultra(-)droite*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ultra-droite).

- À quand remonte et quelle est l'origine de l'emploi d'*ultra(-)droite* ?
- Lequel des degrés de [*extrême*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/extr%C3%AAme) et [*ultra-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ultra-) (l'élément formant) est-il du plus haut niveau généralement dans la formation de composés ; spécifiquement ici comme complément d'un nom (avec le vecteur du spectre de l'opinion, *gauche/droite*) ?

  - L'*ultra-droite* est-il une surenchère d'*extrême-droite* et le cas
    échéant en restreint-il la portée relative ou est-ce le besoin d'avoir indépendamment un substantif et une locution nominale qui explique leur coexistence ou autrement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> À quand remonte et quelle est l'origine de l'emploi d'ultra(-)droite ?

Elle est attestée au moins en 1968 (François Duprat, en parlant de Ronald Reagan) mais ne se répand vraiment qu'à partir des années 80.

Elle tire peut-être son origine de l'américain *ultra-right* qui semble antérieure :

1949 *He became a member of this then unpopular group in the Party, condemned by such people as Stafford Cripps as ultra-Right-wing and reactionary.* Daniel Lerner, *Sykewar*, 1949.

1951 *There was a slight trend from Right to ultra-Right*. Herbert David Croly, *The New Republic*

1961 (To Robert S. McNamara) *Dear Mr. Secretary : Enclosed please find a report prepared by the Socialist Party-Social Democratic Federation on the activities of extremist ultra-right groups and their impingement upon the Armed Forces of the United States.*

[Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_right_(United_States)) fait aussi référence à *ultraright*

> Further to the right of the radical right, they identified an "ultraright". Most ultraright groups operate outside political life, call for drastic change and in extreme cases they use violence against the state.

Une autre origine pourrait être une construction inspirée par le mot *[ultraroyaliste](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraroyaliste)* (plus royaliste que le roi) attribué à Joseph Fouché :

> « Comme elle disait au commencement de la révolution les aristocrates, elle dit aujourd'hui les ultra-royalistes. Les journaux étrangers à sa solde ou dans ses intérêts écrivent tout simplement les ultra. Nous sommes donc des ultra, nous tristes héritiers de ces aristocrates dont les cendres reposent à Picpus et au cimetière de la Madeleine. » Chateaubriand, *De la Monarchie selon la charte*, 1816

---

> Lequel des degrés de extrême et ultra- (l'élément formant) est-il du plus haut niveau

En français au moins, ultra- est généralement perçu comme d'un niveau plus élevé. Les extrêmes sont à l'intérieur de l'hémicycle, même s'ils en touchent les bord (les extrémités) alors que les ultras se situent au-delà de (outre) ces limites. Une lumière extrêmement violette est visible, une lumière ultraviolette ne l'est pas.

De manière plus générale, *ultra* et *extrême* sont souvent synonymes. Dans ce cas, *ultra* est plus « à la mode » et parfois péjoratif (Ultra-libéralisme / libéralisme extrême, c'est ultra/extrêmement cher/chaud, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

À mon sens c'est une erreur de les considérer comme synonymes, *ultra-droite* est plus fort qu'*extrême droite*. On peut le considérer comme un sous-ensemble de l'extrême droite, mais souvent trop extrême pour être représenté par un parti. J'entends en général ce terme pour parler des néo-nazis, des suprémacistes blancs, du KKK, etc.

Au sens auquel on l'entend récemment, bizarrement il est assez comparable au terme américain *alt-right*, qui ne se traduit pas très bien (même s'ils sont très différents étymologiquement, *alt-right* signifiant *droite alternative*). La différence est sûrement due au fait que le mot *alt-right* a été adopté par ses partisans, alors qu'ultra-droite est plus facilement utilisé par ses détracteurs.

La page [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-right) de l'*alt-right* inclut entre autres les suprémacistes blancs, les séparatistes blancs, les anti-sémites, néo-nazis, néo fascistes, et négationnistes. C'est assez proche de ce qu'on désigne par ultra-droite en Europe.

En tout cas c'est un mot assez jeune (dans son sens actuel) et il ne doit pas encore y avoir de définition précise et admise par tous.

(Pour les termes très récents, [Google Trends](https://trends.google.fr/trends/explore?date=all&q=ultra%20droite) peut être assez utile pour déterminer, sinon la première utilisation, la prise d'ampleur d'un mot. Ngram ne répertorie que jusqu'à 2008)

Comment: Intéressant ce parallèle avec _alternative right_, cet euphémisme qui fait penser à un autre terme adopté par des gens qui jouent sur les mots pourrait-on dire, « alternative facts ». _Trends_ utile. Je vais sélectionner l'autre réponse vu une affirmation formelle sur l'origine, mais bien vu pour l'autre partie de la question.

Comment: @jlliagre L' « adepte du mouvement artistique du suprématisme » : [suprématiste(s)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/supr%C3%A9matiste) ? Tu y voyais un truc sous-jacent comme _groupe(s)_ ? Je ne savais pas que ce nom-là existait... Étrange qu'on puisse avoir _suprémacistes blancs_ et _blancs suprématistes_ à la fois pour le sens dont on discutait mais je ne sais pas si le deuxième n'est pas carrément un calque de l'anglais...

Comment: @Survenant9r7 La réponse de Teleporting Goat utilisait une fois *suprématistes*, une fois *suprémacistes*. J'ai homogénéisé l'orthographe sur le premier qui me semblait le seul correct puisque nous écrivons *suprématie*, pas *suprémacie*. Après réflexion, vu que nous prononçons [-sist] et pas [-tist], *suprématiste* pose (aussi) problème. On devrait peut être dire *suprémacien*, à l'image de *pharmacist/pharmacien* ;-) Je laisse Teleporting Goat avoir le dernier mot...

Comment: @jlliagre Tu as bien fait, j'aurais choisi *suprématiste* aussi :)

Comment: N'hésite pas à faire un _rollback_ si tu veux même si tu sembles avoir approuvé la modification.