# Est-ce un(e) « suprémaciste » ou un(e) « suprématiste » (le nom commun) ?

Tags: vocabulaire, adjectifs, noms, lexique, dictionnaires

Comment orthographie-t-on le nom commun **suprémaciste/suprématiste** (comme dans « suprémaciste blanc ») pour signifier le « [partisan du suprémacisme](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/supr%C3%A9maciste#Nom_commun) », (de [suprématie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/supr%C3%A9matie#fr) ; l'« idéologie raciste qui considère qu’une race ou qu'une ethnie particulière peut et doit exercer une domination sur une ou plusieurs autres » [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/supr%C3%A9macisme)) ? Est-ce supréma**c**iste ou [supréma**t**iste](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/supr%C3%A9matiste#Nom_commun) ?  Wiktionnaire dit [suprémaciste](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/supr%C3%A9maciste#Nom_commun). GDT dit [suprémaciste](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26544113). Termium dit [suprémaciste](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=supr%C3%A9maciste&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs). Le TLFi, Larousse en ligne, Ac.8/9 et le site web de l'Académie ne disposent pas du terme.

On notera cependant que Wiktionnaire identifie à la fois, quoique avec une légère différence en termes de sens, l'adjectif [suprémaciste](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/supr%C3%A9maciste#Adjectif) pour ce qui est « relatif au suprémacisme » et [suprématiste](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/supr%C3%A9matiste#Adjectif) en deuxième acception pour ce qui « caractérise une philosophie néonazie qui pose le principe la suprématie de la race pure », ce qui rend un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=supr%C3%A9macistes%20blancs%2Csupr%C3%A9matistes%20blancs&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csupr%C3%A9macistes%20blancs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csupr%C3%A9matistes%20blancs%3B%2Cc0) de « suprémacistes/suprématistes blancs » difficile à interpréter. On notera de plus que le nom [suprématiste](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/supr%C3%A9matiste#Nom_commun) peut aussi selon Wiktionnaire signifier « (Arts) Adepte du mouvement artistique du [suprématisme](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/supr%C3%A9matisme) » (« Mouvement d’art abstrait né en Russie au début du XXe siècle. », Wiktionnaire) ce qui n'aide pas non plus. Qu'en est-il ?

Comment: Échange original [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/34347/19187). Source de 1991 : [ici](https://books.google.com/books?redir_esc=y&hl=fr&id=fg8ZAAAAIAAJ&dq=Daniel+Hubert%2C+Yves+Claud%C3%A9%2C+Les+skinheads+et+l%27extr%C3%AAme+droite&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=supr%C3%A9macistes). Solution de _Larousse_ en ligne angl./fr. [ici](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/supremacist/616322).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que ce soit le courant artistique ou l'idéologie, on part du même mot, *suprématie*.

Les dérivés naturels, suivant les usages du français, sont *suprématiste* et *suprémaciste*.

Aujourd'hui, les adeptes du mouvement artistique ne sont pas légion mais ceux du mouvement idéologique sont souvent cités par les médias. La prononciation est alors toujours calquée sur celle de l'anglais *supremacist*.

Ceci pose un problème car le **t** de supréma**t**ie se prononce [**s**] mais dans tous les mots en **-tiste** (à l'exception éventuelle de *suprématiste*), le **t** garde sa prononciation [**t**].

Si l'on observe les usages d'autres langues, on observe que la plupart différencient les deux sens par l'orthographe et la prononciation :

- Le russe, à l'origine de la première occurrence distingue *Супрематизм* (-matism) pour le mouvement artistique et *Супремасизм* (-masism) pour l'idéologie.
- L'anglais a *suprematist* et *supremacist*.
- Le néerlandais *suprematistische* et *supremacist*.
- L'espagnol, le [catalan](https://termcat.blog.gencat.cat/2019/02/07/supremacisme-o-suprematisme/), le portugais et l'italien *suprematista* et *supremacista*.
- Le roumain *supremacismul* et *suprematismul*.

Seul l'allemand ne semble avoir qu'un seul mot :

- *Suprematisten*.

En français, on trouve *suprémaciste* dans la thèse de doctorat ès Lettres de Judith Lavoie, *La parole noire en traduction française, le cas Huckleberry Finn* (1998)

> En effet, Twain a recours à des procédés variés pour subvertir et critiquer
> les préjugés racistes qui organisent le discours suprémaciste blanc.

Au vu de l'usage majoritaire d'une graphie différenciée, en particulier par les autres langues romanes, il ne fait pas de doute que le mot ***suprémaciste***, déjà très présent dans les journaux et magazines, et ajouté au Petit Robert en 2016 (*partisan d'une idéologie qui postule la suprématie d'un groupe d'individus*), finira par s'imposer pour l'idéologie, et ***suprématiste*** sera limité au courant artistique. *Suprémaciste* a aussi l'avantage de la double proximité avec *raciste*.

Answer (score 1):

Selon mon « analyse » (plus que sommaire) du corpus de *Google Books* dont le traitement s'arrête en **2008** :

- On trouvait à première vue un peu moins de **40% de plus** d'emplois de
  *suprématistes* comme nom au pluriel que pour *suprémacistes*.
- On trouvait à première vue un peu plus de **55% de plus** d'emplois
  de *suprématistes blancs* que pour *suprémacistes blancs* (où
  *ngram* assurait que *suprémacistes* était employé comme nom alors qu'il était incapable de
  l'assurer avec *suprématistes* même si les résultats montrent que c'était très souvent le cas.).
- Quand on laisse *ngram* trouver des cooccurrences significatives au
  corpus, il n'associe *suprémacistes* qu'avec « blancs » alors que
  *suprématistes* donne entre autres « russes ». On ne sait pas si ça relève des deux sens rattachés à *suprématiste*.
- Peut-être que *suprématistes* s'emploie davantage seul ou en coordination que *suprémacistes*. On ne sait pas si ça relève des deux sens rattachés à *suprématiste*.
- Les courbes « polies » semble illustrer une tendance récente (précédant 2008) de la progression de *suprémacistes* ou *suprématistes* dans certains cas mais les résultats des deux graphiques sont à certains égards contradictoires et on n'a pas la patience pour éplucher les résultats.

[image]

<sub>Image d'une requête épurée basée sur la requête : `(suprématistes-suprématistes_NOUN),(suprémacistes - suprémacistes_NOUN),(suprémacistes - suprémacistes_ADJ),(suprématistes - suprématistes_ADJ),suprémacistes_NOUN,suprématistes_NOUN,suprématistes_ADJ,suprémacistes _ADJ_,suprématistes _ADJ_`</sub>

[image]

<sub>Image d'une requête épurée basée sur la requête : `suprémacistes_NOUN blancs,suprématistes_NOUN blancs,suprémacistes blancs,suprématistes blancs,suprématistes_ADJ blancs,suprémacistes_NOUN blancs_ADJ,suprématistes _ADJ_,suprémacistes _ADJ_,suprématistes *,suprémacistes *`</sub>

---

Un *ngram* ne détermine pas l'orthographe d'un mot mais peut ajouter à la réflexion. Les deux graphies existent, on vérifiera éventuellement dans des dictionnaires afin de déterminer si l'une s'impose.

Answer (score 0):

Dans votre contexte, on utilise uniquement : **suprémaciste**

Answer (score -1):

Ces mots sont des néologismes pas si récents (voir commentaires), cependant ils ne se trouvent pas dans les dictionnaires principaux du français ; on peut se rabattre sur la littérature récente au moyen d'un ngram. 
On voit alors que l'orthographe est « suprématiste » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=les+supr%C3%A9matistes%2Cles+supr%C3%A9macistes&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cles%20supr%C3%A9matistes%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cles%20supr%C3%A9matistes%3B%2Cc0)). La forme « les suprémacistes » est très minoritaire, on trouve en forte majorité « les suprématistes ». On retrouve cette écrasante majorité pour « [des suprématistes](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=des+supr%C3%A9macistes%2Cdes+supr%C3%A9matistes&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdes%20supr%C3%A9matistes%3B%2Cc0) ».